# A property of compact subsets of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,\varrho)$ be a metric space and $K\subset X$ compact.

Then, for every $\,\varepsilon > 0$, $\,K$ can be covered with a finite number of balls of radius $\varepsilon$. Show that the reciprocal is not true.

**My approach.** Since $K$ is compact, every open cover of $K$ contains a finite sub-cover. But every one of the open sets of the finite sub-cover can written as a union of open balls with radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Might be of interest to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433937/why-does-totally-bounded-need-complete-in-order-to-imply-compact

Comment: "But every one of the open sets..." Why is that true? That seems like circular reasoning...

Comment: Equivalently: every compact set is [totally bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space)

Answer (score 4):

Let $K$ be compact, then 
$$
\{B(x,\varepsilon) : x\in K\}
$$
is an open cover of $K$, and hence it has a finite subcover:
$$
K\subset B(x_1,\varepsilon)\cup\cdots\cup B(x_n,\varepsilon).
$$ 
Note however, that every non-compact subset of this compact set $K$ has the same property, as it can also be covered by finitely many such balls.

In particular, every bounded (and hence not necessarily compact) subset of $\mathbb R$ can be covered by finitely many such balls.